# r - filter by date with group by condition

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by

In R, using `dplyr` I want to filter greater than a date in for each group.

Below gives me the results, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to get the same thing. Is it possible to filter without using `mutate`?

```
max_dates <- data.frame(col_1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'), max_date = c('2021-08-23', '2021-07-19', '2021-07-02'))


df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10), rep('c', 10)),
                 date = rep(seq(as.Date('2021-07-01'), by = 'week', length.out = 10), 3))

desired_df <- df %>% 
  left_join(max_dates, by = 'col_1') %>% 
  mutate(greater_than = ifelse(date >= max_date, T, F)) %>% 
  filter(greater_than)
```

Comment: Yes, just move your `date >= max_date` into `filter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the mutate argument; move the conditional to the filter argument...

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(max_dates, by = 'col_1') %>% 
    filter(date >= max_date)
#>    col_1       date   max_date
#> 1      a 2021-08-26 2021-08-23
#> 2      a 2021-09-02 2021-08-23
#> 3      b 2021-07-22 2021-07-19
#> 4      b 2021-07-29 2021-07-19
#> 5      b 2021-08-05 2021-07-19
#> 6      b 2021-08-12 2021-07-19
#> 7      b 2021-08-19 2021-07-19
#> 8      b 2021-08-26 2021-07-19
#> 9      b 2021-09-02 2021-07-19
#> 10     c 2021-07-08 2021-07-02
#> 11     c 2021-07-15 2021-07-02
#> 12     c 2021-07-22 2021-07-02
#> 13     c 2021-07-29 2021-07-02
#> 14     c 2021-08-05 2021-07-02
#> 15     c 2021-08-12 2021-07-02
#> 16     c 2021-08-19 2021-07-02
#> 17     c 2021-08-26 2021-07-02
#> 18     c 2021-09-02 2021-07-02
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We may use non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date1 := date][max_dates,  on = .(col_1, date1 >= max_date)]
```

-output

```
 col_1       date      date1
 1:     a 2021-08-26 2021-08-23
 2:     a 2021-09-02 2021-08-23
 3:     b 2021-07-22 2021-07-19
 4:     b 2021-07-29 2021-07-19
 5:     b 2021-08-05 2021-07-19
 6:     b 2021-08-12 2021-07-19
 7:     b 2021-08-19 2021-07-19
 8:     b 2021-08-26 2021-07-19
 9:     b 2021-09-02 2021-07-19
10:     c 2021-07-08 2021-07-02
11:     c 2021-07-15 2021-07-02
12:     c 2021-07-22 2021-07-02
13:     c 2021-07-29 2021-07-02
14:     c 2021-08-05 2021-07-02
15:     c 2021-08-12 2021-07-02
16:     c 2021-08-19 2021-07-02
17:     c 2021-08-26 2021-07-02
18:     c 2021-09-02 2021-07-02
```